# Cannot read property 'gmap' of null

Tags: extjs

I'm learning how to use the Ext.js framework, and I built a map using Google API, I'm using the GMapPanel widget.

I'm having some issues to identify the widget when the application is initialized. I would like to get the map on Controller, but I keep receiving this errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gmap' of null
>       at constructor.init (MapController.js?_dc=20151109082919:46)
>       at new constructor (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:63176)
>       at constructor [as self] (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:12296)
>       at Object.widget (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:14662)
>       at constructor.create (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:26228)
>       at constructor.lookupComponent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123938)
>       at constructor.prepareItems (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:124418)
>       at constructor.add (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123436)
>       at constructor.initItems (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123861)
>       at constructor.initComponent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=20151109082919:123821

I'm using the following code on controller:

```
init: function () {

var me = this;
var w = me.getView();

var flightPathCoordinates = [
        {lat: (...), lng: (...)},
        {lat: (...), lng: (...)},
        {lat: (...), lng: (...)},
        {lat: (...), lng: (...)}
];


var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPathCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#42ffcf',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 5
});

flightPath.setMap(w.down('gmappanel').gmap);
```

I had to do something similar to what I'm trying to do now and it worked, but this function is called when someone clicks at a specific button.

```
startViewer: function (btn) {

...

var map = btn.up('map');

...

flightPath.setMap(btn.up('map').gmap);  

}
```

Now I would like to do the same thing that I did on startViewer() function but automatically when someone starts the application, how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd use the `boxready` ([api](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#event-boxready)) event to do something like this. That event fires once and only once - when a component is done completing it's layout. So typically you'd listen for that and when it's done you can execute whatever code you want. So in your window config, you'd do something like:

```
listeners: {
  boxready: function(w){
      var map = w.down('gmappanel').gmap;
      //etc
  }
}
```

However, in this case that won't work because even though your window might be done with it's layout, the gmappanel might still be creating the actual google map. So to accommodate for this you can instead use the `mapready` event that gmappanel provides. So then you'd do something like this for your window config:

```
items: [{
   xtype: 'gmappanel',
   listeners: {
      mapready: function(gmappanel){
          var map = gmappanel.gmap;
      }
   }
}]
```